# Items not showing in listbox

Tags: vb.net

I've got a simple list box on my VB form and I'm adding strings to it using the standard `lstBox.items.add("string")` command. However, the items aren't actually showing up in the list box. If I iterate through the items collection I can see that the strings are being added. They just aren't visible in the list box. If I add items to said collection before compilation, using the IDE, they show up fine and I can delete them in the normal way. I have tried deleting and re-adding it but that hasn't helped.

Quite frankly I am stumped, because I have used listboxes hundreds of times and I can't get this to work. So any help would be appreciated.

The exact code to add items to the list is:

```
MainForm.lstPendingJobs.Items.Add(MainForm.currentJob)
```

I have tried moving this subroutine into the mainform class and that didn't help either.

Comment: Have you tried repfreshing the list box after you add an item? Something like `lstBox.Refresh()`. Also, if you add the items via the form class code, dont do `MainForm.lstPendingJobs.Items.Add(MainForm.currentJob)`, but rather `lstPendingJobs.Items.Add(MainForm.currentJob)`

Comment: Refreshing makes no difference, and the reason I need the mainform reference is because the items are getting added from a different class

Comment: `I'm adding strings...` that may not be true depending on what `currentjob` is (a function?  a Type?).  If it is a Type like a class you have, what displays *should* be the return from `ToString()` perhaps something like a NameSpace+TypeName.  Since you say it is blank there is also the chance using default form instance has bitten you.

Comment: `currentjob` is a string that has literally been assigned the line before. The thing that's particularly bugging me is that I know how to add items to listboxes. Even if I simply do `lstPendingJobs.items.add("hello world")` in the mainform class it still doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

Could it have been that you had accidentally altered the DrawMode property from Normal to OwnerDrawFixed or OwnerDrawVariable?

This would account for the non display of the items even though they are in the list box

Comment: This could have been it but I can't check, sorry... In the end I just deleted the project and started from scratch since it was only about an hour in.

Answer (score 0):

item in your case is an object. You need to get a value out of it.

Try `msgbox(item.value)`

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question... The msgboxes show up the contents of the collection just fine. The issue is that these items aren't showing up in the actual list box, just in the collection (the for each loop was just a diagnosis tool I tried)

Comment: In that case can you show how exactly you are populating the listbox... and when.

Comment: Done, and that gets run as part of a subroutine that handles a button click